# PHP radio button check issue

Tags: php, html

No matter which radio button is checked then submitted, **no** is always shown.

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" id="formyes" name="checkyn" value="yes"/>
<label for="formyes">yes</label>
<input type="radio" id="formno" name="checkyn" value="no"/>
<label for="formno">no</label>
```

PHP var dump of $_POST:

```
'checkyn' => string 'no' (length=2)
```

How can I test if **yes** is selected if when **yes** is selected **no** is always logged?

Comment: You should show the PHP code.

Comment: what do you mean by "always logged" ... you could manipulate or manually send a HTTP request containing bullshit but no matter what, 1 variable can only have 1 value (not talking about objects or arrays)

Comment: I mean if yes is checked, the `var_dump($_POST)` shows no, if no is checked it still shows no.

Comment: your code is correct may be problem with you form action and method ..

var_dump($_POST);

http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/j4c-92c

Comment: I've disabled javascript and now its working, I will investigate further.

Comment: The problem was with how I was sending the data in an js object through ajax, I was adding every element with a name to $_POST I just put a conditional in and skipped the loop if the radio wasnt checked

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
if($_POST['checkyn']=='yes')
{
    echo "Yes checked";
}elseif($_POST['checkyn']=='no')
{
   echo "No checked";
}
```

Comment: I know how to check, the problem is no matter if yes or no is selected, no is always set

Comment: <input type="radio" id="formno" name="checkyn" value="no" checked />

Answer (score 0):

You have two button with same name it means that you can select one at a time. if you select one then another will be unselect.
I think you are saying that `$_POST['checkyn']`  is always  give you no. if that the case  you should select one by default in your html:

```
<input type="radio" id="formyes" name="checkyn" value="yes" checked/>
<label for="formyes">yes</label>
<input type="radio" id="formno" name="checkyn" value="no"/>
<label for="formno">no</label>
```

you can get is value like this:

```
  if(isset($_POST['checkyn']) )
    if( $_POST['checkyn'] == 'yes'){

    //yes selected do your stuff
    }
    else{

    //no selected
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if($_POST){
print_r($_POST['checkyn']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML should be

```
<input type="radio" id="formyes" name="checkyn[]" value="yes"/>
<label for="formyes">yes</label>
<input type="radio" id="formno" name="checkyn[]" value="no"/>
<label for="formno">no</label>
```

ADD [  ] after checkyn in HTML this will denote array in PHP

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    $check = $_POST['checkyn'][0];
}
?>
```

if you echo $check; checked button value will return